# Adding a MySQL constraint that a field exists as primary key of the same table

Tags: mysql, primary-key

I'm creating a table that has a `basisId` field as the primary key. There's also another field `parentBasis` which would be a reference to another tuple with `that.basisId` equal to `this.parentBasis`. What I want to do to is express this constraint while creating the table.

Something like: `ADD CONSTRAINT CHECK EXISTS this.parentBasis AS somewhere.basisId` (Obviously not real MySQL).

A quick browse through the [MySQL dev pages](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html) didn't do much good. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using InnoDB then you can create a [foreign key](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) from the table to itself. For example:

```
create table t (
    id int not null primary key,
    parent int null
);
alter table t add constraint foreign key (parent) references t(id);
```

then `t.parent` would either have to be NULL or a `t.id` value.